# Calculating the area of a rectangle with different images

Tags: javascript, area

I am in the process of making a website for calculating the area of differing lego bricks and am unsure on how to do this.  I have created 13ish images of lego bricks with assigned heights and widths.[one has been copied below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d66RI.png) I understand how to do the multiplication and checking (response of user vs actual answer) aspect of this website but don't know how randomise these images and then store the variables for them such as length and width (to calculate the area). Would you be able to suggest any ideas on the javascript for this?

```js
var number1;
var number2;
var response;
var calcanswer;
var score = 0;
window.onload = areaquestion;

var areas = new Array("Images/1*1.png","Images/2*1.png","Images/2*2.png","Images/3*1.png","Images/3*2.png","Images/4*1.png","Images/4*2.png","Images/4*3.png","Images/5*1.png","Images/5*2.png","Images/6*1.png","Images/6*2.png","Images/6*4.png");

function areaquestion() {
     var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * areas.length);
     document.getElementById("question").src = areas[randomNum];
    number1 = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 9 );
    number2 = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 9 );
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this shape?";
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
}

function check()
{
    var statusDiv = document.getElementById("status");
    response=document.getElementById("answer").value;

    if(response != calcanswer)
    statusDiv.innerHTML="Incorrect";
    else
    if (response==calcanswer)
    {
        statusDiv.innerHTML="Very good!";
        score ++;
        document.getElementById("score").textContent = score
        document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
        problem();
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  /* Style the body */
  body {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  /* Header/logo Title */
  .header {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  .score {
    display:flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    float: right;
  }
  
  #answer {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: yellow;
    color:black;
    border-color: black;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    float: initial;
    text-size-adjust: 30;
  }

  #solve {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: blue;
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: black;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Column container */
  .row {  
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  /* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
  /* Sidebar/left column */
  .side {
    flex: 50%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
    color:#000;
  }
  
  /* Main column */
  .main {
    flex: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  
  /* Footer */
  .footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    background: #fff;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  #practicebtn{
    padding:30px;
  }

  #playbtn{
    padding:30px;
  }
  /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .row, .navbar, .footer {   
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Lego Area</title>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Play.css">
    <script src="JavaScript/Play.js"></script>
  </head>
<body onload="problem();">
  
  <div class="header">
    <h1>LEGO AREA</h1>
    <p>Calculating <b>area</b> with Emmet.</p>
    <div id="score" class="score" value="SCORE:"></div>
  </div>
    
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="side">
        <div id="question"></div>
        <div id ="prompt"></div>
        <input type="text" id="answer"/>
        
      </div>

      <div class="main">
        <input id="solve" type="button" value="CHECK!" onclick="check()" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="status"></div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="practice"> <a href="Practice.html"><img src="Images/legoBlue2.png" id="practicebtn"  width="20%"></a></div>
    <div class="play"> <a href="Play.html"><img src="Images/legored2.png" id="playbtn" width="20%"></a></div>
  </div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Based on your filename naming convention of the PNGs, e.g. `2*2.png` you could technically grab the dimensions from the filename itself. And this is how you would go about defining your `number1` and `number2`. ... I can give an example in code if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create an array of objects containing all your legos with key/value pairs indicating the source image, the length, width, and area of each?  Such as:

```js
const legos = [
    {
        name: lego01
        image: "image01.png",
        len: 10,
        wid: 4,
        area: 40
    },
    {
        name: lego02
        image: "image02.png",
        len: 6,
        wid: 6,
        area: 36
    }
    {
        name: lego03
        image: "image03.png",
        len: 12,
        wid: 8,
        area: 96
    }
]
```

Then you can have your program choose a random lego.  And you can access it's area or length and width using the syntax randomLego.width.

I hope I understood what you were wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks!how would you then call on the randomly generated images to display teh question and then check the answer.?